# Heap corruption exception in knnMatch opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, heap-corruption

I'm having Heap corruption exception while compiling this code which I found on the internet. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to solve the problem. 
the exception occurred in the following line:

```
   matcher.knnMatch(desObject, des_image, matches, 2);
```

Could someone tell me what should I replace this line of code with?

The complete source code:

```
cv::initModule_nonfree();
// turn performance analysis functions on if testing = true
bool testing = false;
double t;  // timing variable
// load training image
Mat object = imread("boo2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if (!object.data) {
  cout << "Can't open image";
  return -1;
}
namedWindow("Good Matches", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
// SURF Detector, and descriptor parameters
int minHess = 3000;
vector<KeyPoint> kpObject, kpImage;
Mat desObject, desImage;
// Performance measures calculations for report
if (testing) {
  cout << object.rows << " " << object.cols << endl;
  // calculate integral image
  Mat iObject;
  integral(object, iObject);
  imshow("Good Matches", iObject);
  imwrite("boo2.png", iObject);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  // calculate number of interest points, computation time as f(minHess)
  int minHessVector[] = {100,  500,  1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000,
                         3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500,
                         7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500, 10000};
  int minH;
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open("C:/School/Image Processing/TimingC.csv", std::ofstream::out);
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    minH = minHessVector[i];
    t = (double)getTickCount();
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minH);
    detector.detect(object, kpObject);
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t) / getTickFrequency();
    file << minHess << "," << kpObject.size() << "," << t << ",";
    cout << t << " " << kpObject.size() << " " << desObject.size() << endl;
    t = (double)getTickCount();
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    extractor.compute(object, kpObject, desObject);
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t) / getTickFrequency();
    file << t << endl;
  }
  file.close();
  // Display keypoints on training image
  Mat interestPointObject = object;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < kpObject.size(); i++) {
    if (kpObject[i].octave) {
      circle(interestPointObject, kpObject[i].pt, kpObject[i].size, 0);
      string octaveS;
      switch (kpObject[i].octave) {
        case 0:
          octaveS = "0";
          break;
        case 1:
          octaveS = '1';
          break;
        case 2:
          octaveS = '2';
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      putText(interestPointObject, octaveS, kpObject[i].pt,
              FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, cvScalar(0, 0, 250), 1, CV_AA);
    }
  }
  imshow("Good Matches", interestPointObject);
  imwrite("C:/School/Image Processing/bookIP2.jpg", interestPointObject);
  cvWaitKey(0);
}
// SURF Detector, and descriptor parameters, match object
// initialization
minHess = 2000;
SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHess);
detector.detect(object, kpObject);
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
extractor.compute(object, kpObject, desObject);
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
// Initialize video and display window
VideoCapture cap(1);  // camera 1 is webcam
if (!cap.isOpened()) return -1;
// Object corner points for plotting box
vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0);
obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(object.cols, 0);
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(object.cols, object.rows);
obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, object.rows);
// video loop
char escapeKey = 'k';
double frameCount = 0;
float thresholdMatchingNN = 0.7;
unsigned int thresholdGoodMatches = 4;
unsigned int thresholdGoodMatchesV[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
  thresholdGoodMatches = thresholdGoodMatchesV[j];
  // thresholdGoodMatches=8;
  cout << thresholdGoodMatches << endl;
  if (true) {
    t = (double)getTickCount();
  }
  while (escapeKey != 'q') {
    frameCount++;
    Mat frame;
    Mat image;
    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    Mat des_image, img_matches, H;
    vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
    vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;
    vector<DMatch> good_matches;
    vector<Point2f> obj;
    vector<Point2f> scene;
    vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    detector.detect(image, kp_image);
    extractor.compute(image, kp_image, des_image);
    matcher.knnMatch(desObject, des_image, matches, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows - 1, (int)matches.size()); i++)
        // THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
        {
      if ((matches[i][0].distance <
           thresholdMatchingNN * (matches[i][1].distance)) &&
          ((int)matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int)matches[i].size() > 0)) {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
      }
    }
    // if (good_matches.size()<1)
    // good_matches.resize(0,cv::DMatch);
    // Draw only "good" matches
    drawMatches(object, kpObject, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches,
                Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(),
                DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    if (good_matches.size() >= thresholdGoodMatches) {
      // Display that the object is found
      putText(img_matches, "Object Found", cvPoint(10, 50),
              FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, cvScalar(0, 0, 250), 1, CV_AA);
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
        // Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(kpObject[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(kp_image[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
      }
      H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);
      perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
      // Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene
      // image )
      line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(object.cols, 0),
           scene_corners[1] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
      line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(object.cols, 0),
           scene_corners[2] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
      line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(object.cols, 0),
           scene_corners[3] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
      line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(object.cols, 0),
           scene_corners[0] + Point2f(object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    } else {
      putText(img_matches, "", cvPoint(10, 50), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 3,
              cvScalar(0, 0, 250), 1, CV_AA);
    }
    // Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);
    escapeKey = cvWaitKey(10);
    // imwrite("C:/School/Image Processing/bookIP3.jpg", img_matches);
    if (frameCount > 10) escapeKey = 'q';
  }
  // average frames per second
  if (true) {
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t) / getTickFrequency();
    cout << t << " " << frameCount / t << endl;
    cvWaitKey(0);
  }
  frameCount = 0;
  escapeKey = 'a';
}
// Release camera and exit
cap.release();
```

Comment: You got the exception while *compiling* the code or *running* the code?

Comment: I got the exception while running the code. the operating system is windows7

Comment: You can refer following SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074401/2724703 to understand how to debug heap corruption on windows based platform.

Comment: if it did not find any descriptors, des_image is empty, and you're indexing matches[-1]